GraphQL mutation for updating products is not working
im trying to implement a python script that will update every product's alt text image to a specific text.
My code initially is this:
import requests
import json
import re
# Define your Shopify store's API key and password
API_KEY = '88xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf'
PASSWORD = '0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4'
API_TOKEN = 'shpat_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

SHOPIFY_DOMAIN = 'https://www.xxxx.yyyy/'
# Define your Shopify store's GraphQL endpoint
GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.xxxx.yyyy/admin/api/2024-04/graphql'

headers = {
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': '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',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

# Define the mutation template
mutation_template = """
mutation updateImageAltText($productId: ID!, $imageId: ID!, $newAltText: String!) {
  productImageUpdate(productId: $productId, image: {id: $imageId, altText: $newAltText}) {
    image {
      id
      altText
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
"""

# Function to send the mutation
def send_mutation(product_id, image_id, new_alt_text):
    # Prepare the mutation variables
    variables = {
        "productId": product_id,
        "imageId": image_id,
        "newAltText": new_alt_text
    }

    # Prepare the GraphQL request payload
    payload = {
        "query": mutation_template,
        "variables": variables
    }
    # Send the GraphQL mutation request
    response = requests.post(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, json=payload, headers=headers)
    # Check for successful response
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(f"Alt text updated successfully for image {image_id}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to update alt text for image {image_id}. Response: {response.text}")

But when im executing the code even if it is successfull the updated are not seen. I have tried running a fetch query with graphql but im getting this response which is quite weird
# GraphQL query
query = """
query MyQuery {
  products(first: 50) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        images(first: 1) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              altText
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
"""

# JSON payload
payload = {
    "query": query
}

# Make the POST request
response = requests.post(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, json=payload, headers=headers)

# # Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the JSON response
    data = response.json()
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
else:
    print(f"Query failed to run with a status code {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)

-------------------------OUTPUT---------------------------
b'<html>\n  <body>\n    <noscript>\n      <a href="https://accounts.shopify.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=7ee65a63608843c577db8b23c4d7316ea0a01bd2f7594f8a9c06ea668c1b775c&amp;destination_uuid=4aa9e194-f056-4326-b911-141e3efda215&amp;nonce=9ecd58f45954fd0d7d9e7b886e8a1231&amp;prompt=merge&amp;redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fc6859c-2.myshopify.com%2Fadmin%2Fauth%2Fidentity%2Fcallback&amp;response_type=code&amp;scope=email%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fdestinations.readonly%20openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fpartners.collaborator-relationships.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fbanking.manage%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fmerchant-setup-dashboard.graphql%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fshopify-chat.admin.graphql%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fflow.workflows.manage%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Forganization-identity.manage%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fmerchant-bank-account.manage%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fshopify-tax.manage&amp;state=d20d4aa1e3781ba66b325f770fe4a923&amp;ui_locales=en&amp;ux=shop">Continue</a>\n    </noscript>\n\n    <script type="text/javascript"
                defer>\n
                window.location="https:\\/\\/accounts.shopify.com\\/oauth\\/authorize?client_id=7ee65a63608843c577db8b23c4d7316ea0a01bd2f7594f8a9c06ea668c1b775c\\u0026destination_uuid=4aa9e194-f056-4326-b911-141e3efda215\\u0026nonce=9ecd58f45954fd0d7d9e7b886e8a1231\\u0026prompt=merge\\u0026redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fc6859c-2.myshopify.com%2Fadmin%2Fauth%2Fidentity%2Fcallback\\u0026response_type=code\\u0026scope=email%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fdestinations.readonly%20openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fpartners.collaborator-relationships.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fbanking.manage%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fmerchant-setup-dashboard.graphql%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fshopify-chat.admin.graphql%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fflow.workflows.manage%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Forganization-identity.manage%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fmerchant-bank-account.manage%20https%3A%2F%2Fapi.shopify.com%2Fauth%2Fshopify-tax.manage\\u0026state=d20d4aa1e3781ba66b325f770fe4a923\\u0026ui_locales=en\\u0026ux=shop"
                ;\n
    </script>\n  </body>\n</html>\n'

What am i missing? Any ideas?

It looks like you're not authenticating properly on your query

i dont know..im following the docs
